# Has anyone else seen this? Single click on custom button triggers Apex method twice

Tags: javascript, custom-button, internet-explorer, ie-11

In our system we have a custom button on a standard Account detail window that calls an Apex method to create a pre-filled Opportunity. In our environment, where Internet Explorer 11 runs inside a thin client, it is quite easy to double click this button and thus call the Apex method twice. The click is not handled fast enough.

This is not possible using, e.g., Firefox on plain Windows. There the browser + the internet connection is just too fast.

But now I have a user who swears that she doesn't double click, yet the method is called twice. I see that two Opportunity objects are created within 2 seconds. It is not easy to see if this happens to other users as well, it could be that they do not notice or complain.

I trust this user, if she says she doesn't double click, then she doesn't.

Has anyone else seen this? Anyway to prevent it? I am afraid that for the time being, we are stuck with IE11.

The Javascript code is

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/41.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/41.0/apex.js")}
window.location = sforce.apex.execute("OpportunityUtil","createOppAndReturnProductPickerURL",{accountId:"{!Account.Id}",contactId:"{!Contact.Id}"});
```

and to be complete, this is the called Apex code:

```
webservice static String createOppAndReturnProductPickerURL(Id accountId, Id contactId) {
Account a = [SELECT Id, Name
             FROM Account
             WHERE Id = :accountId][0];

Opportunity o = new Opportunity(
    AccountId = accountId,
    Name = '' + Date.Today().year() + '-' + Date.Today().month() + '-' + Date.Today().day() + ' - ' + a.Name,
    StageName = 'Onderhandeling',
    CloseDate = Date.Today().addDays(14),
    Contactpersoon__c = (contactId == null) || String.isBlank((String)contactId) ? null : contactId);
insert o;

return PICK_PRODUCTS_PAGE + '?oppId=' + o.Id;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68109/discussion-on-question-by-sander-de-jong-has-anyone-else-seen-this-single-click).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reply as a comment, but it is just too much code and it looks horrible...

Why don't you disable your own button before calling your code?

If your button name is `disableme`, the code would be something like...

```js
function disable(button){
    document.getElementsByName(button)[0].setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
    document.getElementsByName(button)[0].className = "btnDisabled";
    document.getElementsByName(button)[1].setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
    document.getElementsByName(button)[1].className = "btnDisabled";
}
function enable(button){
    document.getElementsByName(button)[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementsByName(button)[0].className = "btn";
    document.getElementsByName(button)[1].removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementsByName(button)[1].className = "btn";
}

disable('disableme');
window.location = sforce.apex.execute(... /* As per @Derek F suggestion */, {
    onSuccess: function(){
        enable("disableme");
    },onFailure: function(){
        alert("call failed"); 
        enable("disableme");
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, the common pattern here is to disable the button via javascript in the event handler, run the code, and then re-enable the button afterwords. +1 from me.

Comment: After a good deal of testing, this also works even if you don't have control of the event handler. For sake of responsiveness, OP will probably want to execute the apex asynchronously by passing `{onSucess: function(){}, onFailure: function(){alert("call failed");}` as the final parameter to `sforce.apex.execute()`. In that case, it's safe to re-enable the button in the `onSuccess` callback function.

Comment: Added your suggestion to the post ;)

Comment: After I implemented this answer, various Firefox users started to complain about the button being disabled before they had clicked on it. So I added if (!!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode) before the disable call, so that it is only done for IE users. But that didn't help, both Firefox and now also IE users kept complaining about the button being randomly disabled before a click. So I had to take it all away. The cure had become worse than the disease.